# SQL view all courses for one student

Tags: mysql, sql, select, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables

**table_student**
ID, firstname, lastname

**table_courses**
ID, course_name

**table_student_course**
ID, student_ID, course_ID, date_taken

All I want to do is list all courses by course_name and date_taken by student with ID=1

Anyone please?

Comment: What does `id` in the student_course table do?

Comment: Just join all 3 tables?

Comment: @jarlh why 3 tables ?

Comment: @Strawberry 2 needs to join to get the `coursename` OR I am missing something

Comment: @Strawberry I suspect it is the primary key which in MySQL is by default the clustering key. This is not nothing at all. I imagine what you are inferring is the Joe Celko school of thought that is anti-surrogate keys, but assuming a student can take the same course more than once you would have to use `(student_ID, course_ID, date_taken)` in order to uniquely identify a record - this is neither narrow nor ever increasing, two guidelines for a good clustering key. If it is possible to enroll on a course, then delay the start you then have a primary key that can change, again terrible practise.

Comment: @GarethD I'm familiar with Celko's stance, but I'm not opposed to surrogate keys *per se*. On the assumption that no course can be taken twice at the same time by the same student then, in this instance, there appears to be a perfectly valid natural key. Things that are 'taken' happen in the past and cannot change.

Comment: *"On the assumption that no course can be taken twice"* - Why would you assume that? People often fail a course and have to repeat it. Even if this assumption is true, since this is MySQL the consideration for the primary key must extend to the clustering key, just because you have a valid natural key, does not necessarily mean it is a good idea, as mentioned ideally the clustering key should be static, narrow, unique and ever increasing. So an ID column will still satisfy this better.

Comment: I am not suggesting there is a right or a wrong way, nor do I want a debate on natural vs surrogate keys, my point is that it is not clear cut enough to warrant seeking out a problem with the OP's schema that may or may not exist and has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `JOIN` on the `table_courses` and `table_student_course` tables and then apply the `Order By` on `cource_name` to sort out by course name.And for selecting the particular student apply the `Where` clause as filter.

```
  SELECT 
      t.course_name,
      tsc.date_taken 
  FROM 
      table_courses t INNER JOIN table_student_course tsc
          ON t.ID = tsc.course_ID
  WHERE
      tsc.student_ID = 1
  ORDER BY 
       t.course_name
```

If you also want to get the students detail from the query then you need to join the 3 tables like below,

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, c.course_name, sc.date_taken 
FROM table_courses c 
INNER JOIN table_student_course sc ON c.ID = sc.course_ID
INNER JOIN table_student s ON sc.student_ID = s.ID
WHERE sc.student_ID = 1
ORDER BY c.course_name
```

Comment: Feel free to accept as answer if you don't know how to accept it take a [look here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

By using Inner Join on the tables "table_courses" & "table_student_course" we selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables making sure the ids are the same. If the condition is met( student_id=1) then the query will return what is expected.

```
SELECT course_name, date_taken
FROM table_courses c INNER JOIN table_student_course sc ON c.id = sc.course_id
WHERE sc.student_ID = 1
ORDER BY course_name
```

Comment: Add further explanation about your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, c.course_name, sc.date_taken 
FROM table_courses c 
INNER JOIN table_student_course sc ON c.ID = sc.course_ID
INNER JOIN table_student s ON sc.student_ID = s.ID
WHERE sc.student_ID = 1
ORDER BY c.course_name
```

Comment: This does answer the question - it would be a better answer if it explained to the original poster what the essential elements of the code does.

Comment: it was used in the top voted answer eventually anyway